# is there a primary antiderivative for this function?

Tags: calculus, integration

I came across this integral in my maths textbook.

$\int\dfrac{\left(x^2-2\right)\mathrm{e}^x}{\left(x-1\right)\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

after close to 30 minutes of trying u-sub, trig sub, integration by parts I gave up and plugged it into wolfram-alpha and the following integral calculator - https://www.integral-calculator.com/. Wolfram alpha couldn't compute an elementary antiderivative. I am confused however by the response on the latter.

It couldn't compute a " manual antiderivative" and displayed: " No antiderivative could be found within the given time limit, or all supported integration methods were tried unsuccessfully. Note that many functions don't have an elementary antiderivative. "

However under " ANTIDERIVATIVE COMPUTED BY MAXIMA " it displayed the following function.

$-\dfrac{\sqrt{1-x}\sqrt{x+1}\mathrm{e}^x}{x-1}$

I differentiated this and confirmed it is infact the anti derivative but what method should I employ to obtain the computed antiderivative? And why did wolfram alpha display there's no elementary anti derivative whereas the other website could compute one?

Comment: **Maple** can solve,but **Mathematica** can't.

Answer (score 4):

We have
\begin{equation}
(1) \int \frac{(x^{2}-2)e^{x}}{(x-1)\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}dx = \int \frac{(x^{2}-1)e^{x}}{(x-1)\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}dx - \int \frac{e^{x}}{(x-1)\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}dx.
\end{equation}

Since
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{(x^{2}-1)}{(x-1)\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\right) = -\frac{1}{(x-1)\sqrt{1-x^{2}}},$$
if we integrate by parts $\int \frac{(x^{2}-1)e^{x}}{(x-1)\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}dx$, we obtain

$$\int \frac{(x^{2}-1)e^{x}}{(x-1)\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}dx =  \frac{(x^{2}-1)e^{x}}{(x-1)\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} + \int \frac{e^{x}}{(x-1)\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}dx.$$

Replace it in $(1)$ and we obtain
\begin{equation}\label{a}
 \int \frac{(x^{2}-2)e^{x}}{(x-1)\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}dx = \frac{(x^{2}-1)e^{x}}{(x-1)\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} + \int \frac{e^{x}}{(x-1)\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}dx - \int \frac{e^{x}}{(x-1)\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}dx.
\end{equation}

Thus,
$$\int \frac{(x^{2}-2)e^{x}}{(x-1)\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}dx = \frac{(x^{2}-1)e^{x}}{(x-1)\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} = -\frac{\sqrt{1-x}\sqrt{x+1}\, e^{x}}{x-1}.$$

Comment: Nice and simple solution .....(after reading it). Cheers and (+1)

Answer (score 0):

**Credits to ZAF**

In general, for any function $f(x)$,
$$\int f(x)e^xdx=g(x)e^x+C \Rightarrow f(x)e^x=(g(x)e^x)’=(g(x)+g’(x))e^x   $$
Hence we have
$$\boxed{f(x)=g(x)+g’(x)}$$
All we have to do to find the function $g(x)$ is splitting $f(x)$ into two functions $g(x)$ and its derivative $g’(x).$
Noticing that $$
\frac{d}{d x}\left(\frac{x^2-1}{(x-1) \sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)=-\frac{1}{(x-1) \sqrt{1-x^2}},
$$
we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(x) & =\frac{x^2-2}{(x-1) \sqrt{1-x^2}}=\frac{x^2-1}{(x-1) \sqrt{1-x^2}}-\frac{1}{(x-1) \sqrt{1-x^2}} \\
& =\frac{x^2-1}{(x-1) \sqrt{1-x^2}}+\left(\frac{x^2-1}{(x-1) \sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)^{\prime}
\end{aligned}
$$
We can now conclude that
$$
\int \frac{(x^2-2) e^x}{(x-1)\sqrt{1-x^2}} d x=\frac{x^2-1}{(x-1) \sqrt{1-x^2}} e^x= \sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}} e^x+C
$$